# Monogame + Cordova in one application

Tags: cordova, xna, monogame, apache-cordova

Is it possible to mix Monogame and Apache Cordova in one application?

The goal is to have user interface in HTML/CSS/JS for browsing, and a game started from this UI with a button.

The game and the UI would be separate, which means it's not needed to put any Cordova UI on top of the game. Just either this or this at one time.

I want to target mobiles and desktop (Windows + Mac) too.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: No. I have my game done in Monogame and UI in EmptyKeys and I'm comfortable using that, but I have no experience at all with Cordova and only little skill in HTML/CSS. I'm happy to learn this new stuff, but only if it's going to work at the end - hence the question.